# how to push a uiviewcontroller from uitableview that is a subclass

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` in which I am adding a subclass of a `UITableView` as a subview.

e.g.

```
 @interface ViewController : UIViewController

    @interface ItemList : UITableView
```

in `ViewController` `viewDidLoad` I create a `ItemList` (`itemList`) object and add it to the view of the `viewcontroller`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 ...
  [self.view addSubview:itemList];
}
```

in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of `ItemList` which is a `UITableView` I do not have access to the navigation controller so how do I push another `viewcontroller` on to the `navigationcontroller`?

```
@implementation ItemList
{
 ...
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newViewControllerobject animated:YES];

    }

}
```

Comment: [[self superview] navigationController]. Try this!!

Comment: @hpiOSCoder :by trying the above a view(superView) can be accessed not the viewController

Comment: @AppleDelegate Oopss... that's right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a property eg : `ViewController *mydelegate` in itemList class. 
when you add the itemList in ViewController's `viewDidLoad` add the following

```
 itemList.myDelegate = self;
```

Moving ahead..on did select

```
 @implementation ItemList
@synthesize mydelegate;
    {
     ...
        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

            [myDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:newViewControllerobject animated:YES];

        }

}
```

Comment: ya thats what I thought. I am going to implement it your way until someone suggests different.

Comment: The delegation design pattern used above is best way of designing your code to use protocols(in this case UITableView methods) where necessary between two classes

Answer (score 1):

If you have very first navigationController defined in AppDelegate, you can use the following code to find uppermost navigationController and then push the viewController upon it.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[appDelegate.navigationController.visibleViewController.navigationController pushViewController:newViewControllerobject animated:YES];
```